# VPN providers and connection from a known location

Tags: vpn

I am interested using a VPN service.  I want to visually monitor online  advertisements in different location, Germany, France  Nederlands and the UK.

I would like a VPN provider which both connects from these locations to the  website of interest. It should also allow me to choose the location of the server I connect from.

A big plus would be the ability to compare the website from different connection side by side

Do any providers allow this?

Comment: Voted to close. Valid question, but sales related questions are not wanted here. This is of limited use.

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding of what a VPN is, is a bit lacking.  It sounds like you are more interested in setting up proxies in various countries in order to view a specific website from their point of view.  I don't think you'll find any particular company that would provide this functionality specifically... but there are thousands of proxy companies that would allow this type of functionality.

Comment: Please restrict your answers to something useful and polite.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude.  Just making an observation.  How a VPN operates and situations where you would use it differ greatly from how a proxy operates.  The example you describe seems to be more suited towards a proxy than a VPN.

Comment: Except that he could log into the vpn provider and then his computer would work with the IP from the provider. Suitable solution.

Comment: @Ric, please restrict your comments to something respectful or insightful.

Comment: @TomTom, VPNs do not necessarily allow you to use the remote gateway to access the Internet.

Comment: AH.... VPN PROVICDERS do per definition. What other use wouldd you have? They basically are used to bypass regional location blocks. You apy them for the permission to access their VPN service. his is their business model. Obvioius case of commenting on a topic you dont know about ;)